# 400 bad request when running the pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am new to azure and I'm creating a simple hellow world pipeline. Here is how I create tasks:

```
data_import_step = PythonScriptStep(
      script_name="Data_Load_Preprocessing.py",
      arguments=['--process_output',data_step_output],
      allow_reuse=False,
      outputs=[data_step_output],
      runconfig=RunConfiguration(),
      compute_target=aml_compute,
      source_directory=process_directory
   )
```

I am declaring aml_compute like this:

```
aml_compute = AmlCompute(ws, clustername)
```

and getting workspace like this

```
ws = Workspace.from_config(path="./config.json", auth=interactive_auth)
```

and data_load_preprocessing.py looks like this:

```
def main():
    print("hellow world")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get following error:
ervice invocation failed!
Request: GET ....
Status Code: 400 BadRequest
Error Code: ValidationError
Reason Phrase: Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

Most of 400 error caused by incorrect auth or compute. Please check your workspace configuration/ compute configuration.

This is my workable sample code:

```
ws = Workspace.from_config() 
blob_store = Datastore(ws, "workspaceblobstore")
compute_target = ws.compute_targets["STANDARD_NC6"]
experiment = Experiment(ws, 'MyExperiment') 

input_data = Dataset.File.from_files(
    DataPath(datastore, '20newsgroups/20news.pkl'))
prepped_data_path = OutputFileDatasetConfig(name="output_path")

dataprep_step = PythonScriptStep(
    name="prep_data",
    script_name="dataprep.py",
    source_directory="prep_src",
    compute_target=compute_target,
    arguments=["--prepped_data_path", prepped_data_path],
    inputs=[input_dataset.as_named_input('raw_data').as_mount() ]
    )

prepped_data = prepped_data_path.read_delimited_files()

train_step = PythonScriptStep(
    name="train",
    script_name="train.py",
    compute_target=compute_target,
    arguments=["--prepped_data", prepped_data],
    source_directory="train_src"
)
steps = [ dataprep_step, train_step ]

pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=steps)

pipeline_run = experiment.submit(pipeline)
pipeline_run.wait_for_completion()
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-ml-pipelines#a-simple-python-pipeline

You can check your log for more error details to bug next time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-log-view-metrics#view-and-download-log-files-for-a-run